# error while extracting text using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a text string as shown below:

```
txt = "(2) 1G–1G (0)"
```

And, dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(txt = c('(2) 1G–1G (0)','(1) 1G–1G (4)','(2) 1G–1G (0)'))
```

I was trying to extract numbers within brackets in a way as shown below:

I want extracted result to be in this format:

```
  2 - 0
```

What I am using is this:

```
gsub('.+\\(([0-9]+)\\) 1G–1G \\(([0-9]+)\\).*$', '\\1 \\2', txt)
```

But What I am getting from above is:

```
 "(2) 1G–1G (0)"
```

I am not sure where is mistake. 
Can someone please explain why this code is not working the way I wanted it to work?

Comment: `gsub('.*\\(([0-9]+)\\) 1G–1G \\(([0-9]+)\\).*$', '\\1 - \\2', txt)`

Comment: If you start with ``.+`` there has to be at least 1 character before your bracket, which is not

Comment: `sub(".*\\((\\d+).*\\((\\d+).*","\\1-\\2",txt)`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for help, it worked for single value `txt = "(2) 1G–1G (0)"` but if i use it from dataframe, such as DF$txt it didn't work. anyways, thanks.

Comment: Thanks Onyambu. it works too.

Comment: You could also try: `gsub("[()]",  "",  gsub("\\).*\\(",  " - ",  txt))`

Comment: `gsub('\\w{2}|[)(]', '', txt)`

Comment: Thanks David, Matt, Rawr, Onyambu and Schifini. your suggestions seem not to work on  `DF <- data.frame(txt = c('(2) 1G–1G (0)','(1) 1G–1G (4)','(2) 1G–1G (0)'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
DF$txt <- trimws(gsub("[^()–]*\\(([0-9]+)\\)[^()–]*"," \\1 ",DF$txt))
## => [1] "2 – 0" "1 – 4" "2 – 0"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/49v8gi/1) and the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/8s06md).

**Details**

- `[^()–]*` - any 0+ chars other than `(`, `)` and `-`
- `\\(` - a `(`
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\\)` - a `)` char
- `[^()–]*` - any 0+ chars other than `(`, `)` and `-`

Comment: Thanks for explanation and demo.

Comment: @I_m_LeMarque BTW, if you need the results in a different column, use https://ideone.com/RKZR4s

Answer (score 1):

You could extract them using base `R` with `regexec` and `regmatches` like so:

```
(df <- data.frame(txt = c('(2) 1G–1G (0)','(1) 1G–1G (4)','(2) 1G–1G (0)', 'somejunkhere')))

getNumbers <- function(col) {
  (result <- sapply(col, function(x) {
      m <- regexec("\\((\\d+)\\)[^()]*\\((\\d+)\\)", x, perl = TRUE)
      groups <- regmatches(x, m)
      (out <- ifelse(identical(groups[[1]], character(0)),
                    NA,
                    sprintf("%s - %s", groups[[1]][2], groups[[1]][3])))
    }))
}
df$extracted <- getNumbers(df$txt)
df
```

This yields

```
            txt extracted
1 (2) 1G–1G (0)     2 - 0
2 (1) 1G–1G (4)     1 - 4
3 (2) 1G–1G (0)     2 - 0
4  somejunkhere      <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks Jan for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Do not understand why you would say it does not work:

```
sub(".*\\((\\d+).*\\((\\d+).*","\\1-\\2",DF$txt)
 [1] "2-0" "1-4" "2-0"
```

or even:

```
 transform(DF,extracted=sub(".*\\((\\d+).*\\((\\d+).*","\\1 - \\2",txt))
            txt extracted
1 (2) 1G–1G (0)     2 - 0
2 (1) 1G–1G (4)     1 - 4
3 (2) 1G–1G (0)     2 - 0
```

Comment: Thakns Onyambu for simple solution and helping.